# How to use groovy inside a Eclipse RCP project?

Tags: groovy, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a Eclipse RCP project, and I want to use Groovy inside it. what I try to do is :
1) add "Groovy Nature"
2) create Groovy files under the "src" folder
3) call the groovy class from the "View"'s createPartControl() method.

But I got the “java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fly.island.jface.Test”， and the "fly.island.jface.Test" is a groovy class.

What should I do to use groovy inside the Eclipse RCP project?

Comment: eclipse: 3.6.1, groovy plugin: 1.5.7

Comment: btw, the exception is occurred at run time, not compile time.

Comment: That would be because either your groovy class files are not being placed on a classpath recognized by PDE, or not being compiled at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the latest version of Groovy-Eclipse 2.1.0 (or one of the dev builds).  Update site is here:

http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/

Additionally, there are some steps you need to do to compile the groovy plugins when you the PDE build.  I'd recommend reading:

http://contraptionsforprogramming.blogspot.com/2010/08/groovy-pde-redux.html

Essentially, you need to include the `org.codehaus.groovy` bundle in your rcp app, and then you need to make some changes to the `build.properties` file of your Groovy plugins (explained in detail on the blog post).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest Version of eclipse (3.6) and the groovy plugin? I recall occasionally having problems with the Java and Groovy compilers not finding each other's classes (in the first version of the plugin, it took a lot of fiddling and luck to get it to work at all). The most recent version seems to be pretty good in that regard, though I've been using it only for a few days myself.

Comment: eclipse: 3.6.1, groovy plugin: 1.5.7