# Eclipse RCP with Groovy: cannot create a groovy class

Tags: groovy, eclipse-rcp

I tried to create a groovy class after installing a groovy plugin. But Eclipse RCP system gives me the following message:

Creation of Element Failed

```
Reason: TestGroovy2[in TestGroovy2.groovy[in <default in
<src in <in  org.eclipsercp.hypoberla ]]]] does not exist
```

by the way, the org.eclipsercp.hypoberla is the RCP I'm creating ....

any body could tell me why?

also, if I create a groovy project on Eclipse, I have no problem creating a groovy class there....but I need some groovy script in my RCP project...

any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks.

BTW: I'm using Eclipse V 3.6.

i found the following post and followed exactly as the blog suggested...still, I cannot create a new groovy class....

[How to use groovy inside a Eclipse RCP project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295932/how-to-use-groovy-inside-a-eclipse-rcp-project/4514987#4514987)

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure what you have done exactly.  Did you install Groovy-Eclipse?  Is your Plugin project a Groovy project as well?  What version of Groovy-Eclipse are you running?  At what point do you get the error?  After the wizard closes?  After compilation?

Comment: Hi Andrew,  yes, I did install the most updated Groovy-Eclipse. "Is your Plugin project a Groovy project as well?" - well, I set up a pure RCP by copying the code from Eclipse Rich Client Platform.Designing.Coding.and.Packaging.Java.Applications.  Do I need to do more? Like creating a Groovy nature?   The error occurrs when I tried to create a groovy class.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a Java project. You indeed need to add a groovy nature to it first:

- right click on the project
- configure -> convert to groovy project